# Fastest method for loading large dataset into python

Tags: python, pandas, astropy, mat-file, data-ingestion

I have some relatively large .mat files that I'm reading in to Python to eventually use in PyTorch. These files range in the number of rows (~55k to ~111k), but each has a little under 11k columns, with no header, and all the entries are floats. The data file sizes range from 5.8 GB to 11.8 GB. The .mat files came from a prior data processing step in Perl, so I'm not sure about the mat version; when I tried to load a file using `scipy.io.loadmat`, I received the following error: `ValueError: Unknown mat file type, version 46, 56`. I've tried `pandas`, `dask`, and `astropy` and been successful, but it takes between 4-6 minutes to load a single file. Here's the code for loading using each of the methods I've mentioned above, run as a timing experiment:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from astropy.io import ascii as aio
import numpy as np
import time

numberIterations = 6

daskTime = np.zeros((numberIterations,), dtype=float)
pandasTime = np.zeros((numberIterations,), dtype=float)
astropyTime = np.zeros(numberIterations,), dtype=float)

for ii in range(numberIterations):
   t0 = time.time()
   data = dd.read_csv(dataPath, delimiter='\t', dtype=np.float64, header=None)
   daskTime[ii] = time.time() - t0
   data = 0
   del(data)

   t0 = time.time()
   data = pd.read_csv(dataPath, delimiter='\t', dtype=np.float64, header=None)
   pandasTime[ii] = time.time() - t0
   data = 0 
   del(data)

   t0 = time.time()
   data = aio.read(dataPath, format='fast_no_header', delimiter='\t', header_start=None, guess=False)
   astropyTime[ii] = time.time() - t0
   data = 0
   del(data)
```

When I time these methods, `dask` is by far the slowest (by almost 3x), followed by `pandas` , and then `astropy`. For the largest file, the load time (in seconds) for 6 runs is:

```
dask: 1006.15 (avg), 1.14 (std)
pandas: 337.50 (avg), 5.84 (std)
astropy: 314.61 (avg), 2.02 (std)
```

I'm wondering if there is a faster way to load these files, since this is still quite long. Specifically, I'm wondering if there is perhaps a better library to use for the consistent loading of tabular float data and/or if there is a way to incorporate C/C++ or bash to read the files faster. I realize this question is a little open-ended; I'm hoping to get some ideas for how I can read these files in faster, so there is not a bunch of time wasted on just reading in the files.

Comment: Which one did you measure first? How much RAM does your machine have?

Comment: I measured them in the order presented. However, I did remove the data variable in between each read, so the code was closer to `data = read(dataPath ...); del(data)`. The machine has 64 GB RAM.

Comment: Try in reverse order. Disk caching can make quite a difference

Comment: I don't that's really a problem. I mean, I run this in a for loop, so after I read in the data using `astropy`, the data is removed, and then read in again using `dask`. So, while the order on the first iteration is `dask`, `pandas`, `astropy`, the order mostly disappears after the first loop.

Answer (score 3):

Given these were generated in `perl`, and given the code above works, these are tab-separated text files, not matlab files. Which would be appropriate for `scipy.io.loadmat`.

Generally, reading in text *is* slow, and will depend heavily on compression and IO limitations.

FWIW pandas is already pretty well optimised under the hood, and I doubt you would get significant gains from using C directly.

If you plan to use these files frequently it might be worth using `zarr` or `hdf5` to represent tabular float data. I'd lean towards `zarr` if you have some experience with `dask` already. They work nicely together.

Comment: I don't think converting these files will be worthwhile, since the `perl` program will be part of the pipeline. So, my code will ingest what is output by the `perl` program. As far as reading is concerned, I've seen hints that using `bash` could be beneficial. For example, `readarray` in `bash` takes just a few seconds, but I don't know how to get the result over to python...

Comment: Do you have control over the part of the pipeline that's writing these files? It would be better if they were just written in a binary format to begin with. It also depends on what kind of processing you're doing. Can you break the file into smaller chunks or must you really read it all into memory?

Comment: perl has support for HDF5 if that's an option.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is already not as fast as other formats.

Pandas is *very* slow for large datasets. I don't know what the other answer is talking about.

I went from 3 plus hours to 3 minutes just switching from Pandas to Numpy binary files.

The easiest implementation for you would be using numpy binaries with using numba for anything computation-wise. Numba uses a c++ backend for codes like for loops.

I've tried many different formats and reading into memory or using a memory map is still faster than using something like Dask for most datasets although my datasets are less than 10GB and I have memory to spare.